# Writing these numbers in terms of billions.

Tags: unit-of-measure

27000000= x billions
4500=y billions
500=z billions

So millions~10^6 and billions~ 10^9 so we have a difference of 10^3 hence i divided 27000000 by 1000 to get :
x=0.027billion is the same as 27 million Is this correct?

thousands~10^3 and billions~10^9 so difference of 10^6 so would i do:
4.5 / 10^6 = 0.0000045
hence y = 0.0000045 and z=0.0000005
Are those correct?

Comment: The first one is correct. Edit your question to show how you found it and what you have tried for the other two. We don't usually "tell people" things on this site, we help them figure things out.

Comment: in UK and Germany one billion=$$10^{12}$$

Comment: I had a look on the internet to find 1 billion is 10^9, does this mean my edit would be correct for the case of 10^9 and if billions is 10^12 i will fix these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your all solutions are correct.

In first you are converting millions to billions.

And in next two terms I suppose you are converting thousand to billion. Then its correct.

Answer (score 0):

I won't tell you the answer to y and z, but I will get you a method using the first example

27000000= x billions is equivalent to 27000000 = (x)*1000000000

Therefore, you can find x by dividing both sides by one billion.

Comment: ok so Dr. Sonhard Graubner has informed me one billion is 10^12, however you have used 10^9 which is what i originally found. Which is it??

Comment: I guess that depends where you're from. I know at least in the united states, a billion is $10^{9}$